# Retrieve In-app Products from Android Market

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I read a couple posts saying that Google does not offer any way to retrieve a list of the In-app products available for your app.

I need my application to be able to offer new In-app products dynamically, did anyone come up with an idea other than storing all your products in a database and map product ids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to query the market for your products.

I used an xml dashboard that contains my productIds that match the app market product ids so my products are loaded dynamically in the application and I can enable/disable products without putting up a new build.